# PHP function json_decode will not decode valid JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I want to parse JSON with PHP.  The function: `json_decode` does not return anything.

This is my `index.php` file.

```
<?php
  $jsondata = file_get_contents("test.json");
  $json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
  echo $json['movies'][0]['title'];
?>
```

This is my test.json file

```
{
    "movies":[
            { 
              "title": "Godfather",
              "Genre": "Action",
              "Language": "English"
            }
         ]
}
```

The browser shows no response.  I expect it to print `Godfather`

Comment: Please echo `$jsondata` & share the output.

Comment: { "movies":[ { "title": "Godfather", "Genre": "Action", "Language": "English" } ] }

Comment: Works for me, are you getting any errors?

Comment: One more thing..i find that echo $jsondata works only when i delete the line '$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);', otherwise nothing is displayed

Comment: Nope..am getting nothing displayed..

Comment: You should do a `var_dump($jsondata);`, perhaps there is some additional output you are not expecting.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: turn error reporting on, it will probably explain that json_decode is undefined, which means your php version is too old.

Comment: Ok..Now i'm getting some error saying 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode() in /var/www/t.php on line 8'

Comment: Then @hari8495 json support in not enabled for sure. Just check by running `<?php phpinfo();` if JSON support is enabled or may be you are using an older version of PHP

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/361424/what-happened-to-json-encode-in-13-10-php

Comment: i'm getting some page with a table 'PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.6'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON support is not enabled in your php version. Please check by running `<?php phpinfo()` 
JSON functions were added in `PHP 5.2`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> > You need to update your PHP version to atleast greater than 5.2 to use json functions.